Azure Custom translation model via API
I’m attempting to build the Azure custom translation model generating journey using APIs.
How can I create them using APIs, and are there any related documentation?
I was able to complete this using Custom Translator, but I can’t seem to find the API documentation for the entire procedure, including work space/project creation, model creation and training.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


Use Azure AI Translator APIs
Quickstart: Build, publish, and translate with custom models


According to this document only development options available for custom translator is using portal.
So, there is no rest api options to train, build or publishing the model.
After you publishing the model the Only available api endpoints is translator Text API V3.
Refer this on how to make custom translation via text api  after publishing the model.

Actually, there is an API in preview:
https://microsofttranslator.github.io/CustomTranslatorApiSamples/#/
We used it to automate the entire process of uploading training files, kicking of a training, and publishing the model...although it wasn't easy. For example, you first upload your documents, poll them to see when they finish being 'processed', then you have to get their ids to pass to the create model API. If you need to know when it is done, you also need to poll it's status is "Training  succeeded" or "Deployed", depending on how you set the IsAutoDeploy parameter in the model POST body.
